# Create an output matrix or data frame using apply()

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply, sapply

I've got a frequency cross-tab and would like to use `rep()` with an `apply()` function to make a long column of data for each sample (A01, A02 etc) that I can use for mean and stdev stats. The numbers in columns A01, A02 etc are frequency counts of CAG e.g. 6485 counts of 13 CAG.

I've managed to write the function to give the correct results, but the format doesn't appear to be indexable e.g. using `sumstats$A01` gives `NULL`. I'd also ideally like the rows and columns inverted in the output table, so columns are mean, sd etc.

```
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15), A01 = c(6485,35,132), A02 = c(0,42,56))
sumstats <- sapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
data_e <- rep(data$CAG, x)

list(
  mean = mean(data_e),
  median = median(data_e),
  sd   = sd(data_e)
)
 })

#Output:
#sumstats$A01
#NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$` subsetting is unique to the data.frame class. If you check `class(sumstats)` you will see it is just a simple matrix.

Simply run `sumstats <- as.data.frame(sumstats)` and then you can use

```
sumstats$A01
#$mean
#[1] 13.04495
#
#$median
#[1] 13
#
#$sd
#[1] 0.2874512
```

Is this what you wanted?

**EDIT:**

```
sumstats2 <- as.data.frame(t(sumstats))
res <- data.frame(samples, sumheight, sumstats2)
res
#    samples sumheight     mean median        sd
#A01     A01      6652 13.04495     13 0.2874512
#A02     A02        98 14.57143     15  0.497416
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I think it's getting there. However, when I try to insert the column in my results table it puts in a new column for each sample (A01, A02 etc) with the same value of mean for each row in the column. 

I've tried transposing the sumstats data frame with 

     sumstats2 <- t(sumstats)

Then inserting it into my results table with

    results <- data.frame(samples, sumheight, mode, sumstats2$mean)

The results table has samples in rows and results (mean, mode etc) in columns.

Comment: And don't forget to do data.frame(t(sumstats2)) to keep it as a data.frame so you can subset using `$`. Otherwise you can just be using `sumstats2[,"mean"]` which will work for either a matrix or a dataframe

Comment: Your final answer should be `sumstats <- as.data.frame(t(sumstats))`

Comment: I'm using it with a much bigger dataset and more columns, but I've tried to give a simplified version below

Comment: Amazing thanks, that's working now. One thing, though. I've just added in a mode = mode(data_e). Unfortunately the output is "numeric". Could I please ask if there's a way to make this calculation work?

Comment: The class type should not matter, i'm not sure what mode function you are using - maybe make a new question or search for mode on the site?

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15), A01 = c(6485,35,132), A02 = c(0,42,56))

samples <- c('A01', 'A02')
sumheight <- colSums(data[ , 2:ncol(data)], na.rm=TRUE)

sumstats <- sapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  data_e <- rep(data$CAG, x)

  list(
    mean = mean(data_e),
    median = median(data_e),
    sd   = sd(data_e)
  )
})


sumstats2 <- as.data.frame(t(sumstats))
res <- data.frame(samples, sumheight, sumstats2$mean)
```

Comment: Amazing thanks, that's working now. 

One thing, though. I've just added in a mode = mode(data_e). Unfortunately the output is "numeric". Could I please ask if there's a way to make this calculation work?